# Odoo Is Ignoring All Changes That I do to the model and view

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

**Problem**

I have created a model called '**Treatment Type**' as follow:

```
class TreatmentType(models.Model):
    _name = "clinicsystem.treatmenttype"
    _description = "Clinic System Treatment Type"

    name = fields.Char(string= 'Name', help="Name of The Treatment Type/Catagory")
    index = fields.Integer(string='Index', help="The Index of This Treatment Type For Sorting In Treatment Plan")
    type = fields.Selection([
        ('tooth_based', 'Tooth Based'),
        ('denture_based', 'Denture Based')
    ])
    description = fields.Text()
    isavailable = fields.Boolean(string="Is Available")
```

And also created the view as follow:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="clinicsystem.treatmenttype_form">
      <field name="name">Treatment Type</field>
      <field name="model">clinicsystem.treatmenttype</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Treatment Type Form">
          <sheet>
            <group>
              <field name="index"/>
              <field name="name"/>
            </group>
          </sheet>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Based on that odoo must not show any field except '**Index**' And '**Name**' but all I get is the following:

[image: Treatment Type Form]

**What I Tried**

I tried making changes on the model by adding new fields and changing the view but it does not do any effect. Even if I uninstall the module and reinstall it again, nothing happens.

**But**

When I change the model name from '**clinicsystem.treatmenttype**' to '**clinicsystem.treatmenttypes**' it works. It's like there is a catch saving that view in picture. So I tried to rename the model back to'**clinicsystem.treatmenttype**' and removing the type field from the model as follow:

```
class TreatmentType(models.Model):
    _name = "clinicsystem.treatmenttype"
    _description = "Clinic System Treatment Type"

    name = fields.Char(string= 'Name', help="Name of The Treatment Type/Catagory")
    index = fields.Integer(string='Index', help="The Index of This Treatment Type For Sorting In Treatment Plan")
    # type = fields.Selection([
    #     ('tooth_based', 'Tooth Based'),
    #     ('denture_based', 'Denture Based')
    # ])
    description = fields.Text()
    isavailable = fields.Boolean(string="Is Available")
```

Odoo started raising an error that says the field '**type**' does not exist. I tried to look for a view that has the same model but there is only one that was mentiond above.

Comment: Remove the module name in your view's `id` so it has the value `treatmenttype_form`

Comment: I checked your code and it is working as expected, try to explain all the steps followed to finally have this error?